# Retrieving JSON with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to retrieve JSON with JQuery from: http://www.chirpradio.org/json

How do I retrieve, parse and display that JSON in a web page.

I'm new to JSON and JQuery, and the onsite documentation is a bit difficult to follow.

Thanks,

Moemonty

Comment: Do you know if the site supports JSONP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get past the SOP is to use a proxy(*which also converts it into JSONP*). i.e.:

```
var url = "http://www.chirpradio.org/json";
jQuery.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22"+url+"%22&format=json&callback=?", function(data){
console.log(data.query.results.json);/*where yahoo puts the json object*/
});
```

However, I suggest not to query w/sensitive information(it's insecure). Your use with the radio feed is ok though.

Comment: This works. But what are the drawbacks to this? Are there any tutorials for using JSONP you would recommend? Thank you.

Comment: JSONP is basically JSON and a function, which is javascript. Heres a link to the JSONP proposition(if it may help): http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/