# Retrieving JSON response in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

I'm trying to retrieve the response of this script:

```
<?php
require_once("db_connect.php"); 
$get = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM main");
$genres;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
    $genres[] = $row['name'];
}
echo json_encode($genres); 
?>
```

And get it back in javascript and store it in a variable, so when I do variable[i] in a loop I'll get the ith genre name.

Comment: What JSON does the PHP output?

Comment: @yes123, I've seen similar comments by you. While SO encourages users to accept answers, it's not a requisite to help them. As noted by **John P**, it wasn't constructive regardless of if it may have prompted the user to accept answers. *The ends doesn't justify the means.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('your_script.php', function(genres) {
    // here genres[i] is your i'th genre from the list
});
```

Answer (score 5):

See http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

And also:

- [Parsing jQuery data in JavaScript (JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464188/json-in-jquery)
- [How to use JSON with Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515684/how-to-use-json-with-jquery)
- [Retrieving JSON with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798023/retrieving-json-with-jquery)
- [How to JSON data using $.getJSON from a php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966910/how-to-json-data-using-getjson-from-a-php-file)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you have the PHP script setup correctly. Take a look at [jQuery's getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one -**

```
 require_once("db_connect.php");  
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM main");

    $json = array();
    $total_records = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($total_records >= 1){
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $json[] = $row;
      }
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
```